# Is possible auto-refresh the Shared Links sidebar in Safari 7?

Tags: safari, macos, web-browser, links

Is possible to set auto refresh for the Shared Links sidebar in the new Safari 7. 
There's in "View" menu > Refresh Shared Links, but this doesn't have a shortcut to refresh. So either a way to have the list auto-refresh or assigning a shortcut would help.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Safari 7.0.1 (which is included in OS X 10.9.1):

> **About the update**
> The OS X Mavericks v10.9.1 Update is recommended for all OS X Mavericks users. It improves the stability, compatibility, and security of your Mac. This update includes:
> …
>
> - Includes Safari 7.0.1
>
>   - …
>   - Updates Shared Links periodically when open in the Safari Sidebar

<sup>Source: [About the OS X Mavericks v10.9.1 Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6065)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You can add a shortcut for any menu items in System Preferences > Keyboards > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts